# UITableView sticked to UISearchBar

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, uisearchbar

I have a view with a **UISearchBar**, a [**MCSegmentedControl**](https://github.com/oettam/MCSegmentedControl) and a **UITableView**

This my view when the **UISearchBar** is not active :

[image]

and this is my view when the **UISearchBar** is active

[image]

As you can see, the **UITableView** is sticked to the **UISearchBar** when this one is active, which is not what I want. I would like the **UITableVIew** to stay underneath the [**MCSegmentedControl**](https://github.com/oettam/MCSegmentedControl)

I don't really know what code to put here, so if you need some, feel free to ask.

Does anyone know how to solve this ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You are actually looking at two different UITableViews: yours and the UISearchDisplayController's searchResultsTableView (which is the one that's visible when the searchBar is active). I haven't tried it myself, but I think you should be able to setFrame: on the searchResultsTableView to offset it.

Comment: Sounds interesting, i didn't know that. I'll try to dig into it.

Answer (score 0):

What is the relation between your SegmentedControl and the table ?

I would take a wild guess that you're supplying SegmentedControl as a group header, in which case this might be an expected behaviour.

If not - please post the details.

Comment: Nop, my SegmentedControl is not defined as a group header of the TableView.